# Linear operator exponentials?

Tags: notation, taylor-expansion, banach-spaces, matrix-exponential

A physics book has the following line in it:
$$
f(k)=e^{k\frac{d}{dx}}f(0).
$$
This is, of course, the "correct" Taylor expansion if we write out the series expansion of $e$ and assume that $k$ is a constant. I have heard of the exponentiation of matrices, and the question here is: can we also have the exponents of any general linear operators in Banach spaces? Just cite any relevant references. Also, is the above notation legal in math?

Comment: Not my area of expertise, although it seems to be legal from (5.17) in [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/ch5.pdf)

Comment: See [Holomorphic functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_calculus)

Comment: @RobertIsrael where the teachers were all this time? It's the HEART of the spectral theorem, it does explain why Terence Tao has to write about eigenvectors and eigenfunctions! Finally these lambda terms start to make a deep fundamental sense, directly connected to the differentiation operator. Such a basic fundamental "simple" principle (why someone needs a PhD in mathematical physics and quantum field theory to have a "visceral sense" of eigenvectors?) It's just differentiation operators and Taylor (MacLaurin) series all the way.

Comment: See this video for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O85OWBJ2ayo

And this theorem: https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Taylor_series_operator_commutes_with_differentiation